# A noun before an adjective without a verb

Tags: grammar, adjective-phrases

> The children surrounded the new writer, their eyes and mouths wide
> open

Why this sentece is correct?

As far as I know "open" has an adjective phrase functioning. So, shouldn't we write something like

> ..., their eyes and mouths were wide open.

or

> ..., with their wide open eyes and mouths.

Must not an adjective follow by a subject?

Comment: Putting adjectives after nouns is sometimes done for literary effect. It’s grammatically valid, just uncommon.

Comment: O.K. Let's change the sequence "The children surrounded the new writer, their wide open eyes and mouths". Isn't there a lack "with" there??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called an [absolute construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominative_absolute): it is common in literary writing, but not often used in speech.

The adjective follows the noun because it is predicative, not attributive. *Their eyes and mouths wide open* is similar in construction and meaning to *and their eyes and mouths were wide open.*

Comment: To complete the picture, I would add that it's the verbless analogue of the supplement "being wide open". The supplement must be a non-finite clause.